# Fermat Pseudoprimes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Find the smallest COMPOSITE integer which is a Fermat pseudoprime to every base

$a = {2, 3, ..., 50}$

I came to know that for any base a = 2 or 3 or ... or 50, the possible answer is $2508013 = (53)  (79)  (599).$ In reality, I don't have any clue. Can your prove/explain the procedure to know $2508013 = (53)  (79)  (599)$

Thanks in advance

Comment: A Carmichael number with no prime factor less than $50$ clearly satisfies the given condition.  Your number is such a number.

Comment: So, the first step is to show that there are no smaller Carmichael numbers with no prime factor less than $50$. Then, there is a very good chance that no smaller number has the property because a number pseudoprime to so many bases is very likely to be a Carmichael number, but we cannot be absolutely sure.

Comment: In fact, your number is the smallest Carmichael number without a prime factor less than $50$, so it should be the smallest COMPOSITE number with the given property.

Comment: I checked the numbers upto $10^7$ and your number is actually the smallest number with the given property.  The next ones are $3828001,4335241,6189121,6733693,9439201$

Comment: How to prove mathematically

Comment: @user413696 let $n$ be from $51$ till your number $2508013$ check all the numbers that $2,3,\cdots ,50$ raised to the  $n-1$ modulo $n$ if its equal to $1$ in every case and $n$ is not prime then you have found the smallest number.